# comparing files and creating a new file

Tags: r, file, shell, concatenation

I have a list of transcripts

> ENSMUST00000000001
>
> ENSMUST00000000003
>
> ENSMUST00000000010
>
> ...

and a dataset of expression profiles for transcripts

> ENSMUST00000000001 3536.80209 3663.638964 3200.659615 2865.602080 3295.721742

The list is shorter than the dataset.

I would like to make a new file that includes the expression profiles for all the transcripts in the first file. Any advice in shell or R would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

where file1 is the file containing list of transcripts
and   file2 is the file containing dataset of expression profiles for transcripts

If the requirement is only to compare against the 1st column of the file2:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a)' file1 file2
```

1. The file1 contents are stored in array a.
2. For every line in file2, if 1st column is present in array a, then print.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the R version, for example to do some downstream processing in R:

```
ListOfGenes <- read.table("file1")
Expression <- read.csv("file2", sep="/t", header=FALSE)
Datawish <- subset.data.frame(Expression, Expression$V1 %in% ListOfGenes)
```

I'm assuming your data doesn't have headers in both files. If it does, use header=TRUE for both read csv and read table and instead of V1 use column names.